# kali linux filter by protocol wireshark's pcaps

Tags: networking, kali-linux, wireshark, pcap

I spent the last 2h looking for a way to quikly filter pcaps, it seems that it is possible using cmd/bat on windows but I can't find anything for kali linux.

I have a way too big pcap and I want to reduce it size by creating a new pcap without all the traffic that doesn't intrest me, it is really easy to filter by protocol in wireshark (like "dns") but sadly it is just graphical and wireshark doesn't really delete all the other packets with non-whitelisted protocols. Is it possible to filter the pcap save file directly without coding my own python filtering script ?

Comment: Try tshark to edit the file   ...    https://tshark.dev/edit/

Comment: Depending on how complex the filtering needs to be a tcpdump might do or the more powerful tshark, which is the command line equivalent to wireshark. Both can read pcap, filter it and write to a new pcap file.

Comment: I saw them in my research and couldn't find anything protocol and save related but I might have been too fast on my reading, I am gonna take a second look at them.